# How pass multiple params in beforeEnter() in vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am working on vue router with multiple parameters. I am sending `category` and `id` from route to the next route. My router configuration is as bellow.

```
{
    path: "/services/category/web-details/:category/:id",
    name: "web-details",
    component: () => import("../views/services/category/WebDetails.vue"),
    props: true,
    beforeEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
      store.dispatch('fetchService', {id: routeFrom.params.id, category: routeFrom.params.category} ).then(service2 => {
        routeTo.params.service2 = service2
        next()
      }
       
      )
    }
}
```

It showing error in like bellow, What is the problem i am doing?

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'category')"
```

Comment: `routeFrom.params` isn't undefined, the error likely refers to another piece of code. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem.  The hook is wrong in multiple ways. routeFrom is not guaranteed to be what you expect, i.e. have params. dispatch doesn't return data, this isn't how a store works

Comment: Ok, I will try next time